# PSU making noises when downloading at max internet speed

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting, desktop-computer, noise

When I'm downloading something at my max internet speed, I hear this fast clicking sound like bzzzt from inside the PSU and it stops if I disconnect the ethernet cable or stop the download.

I have a PCI ethernet card, the motherboard connection is dead for a long time. I tried to replace that ethernet card with a new one and change it's PCI slot but that didn't help.

I tried to open the PSU and see if any of the capacitors bulge or leak but they all looked ok, cleaned it from all the dust on the way, didn't help.

It's over 5 years old OCZ 650 watt PSU with a silver rating so it's not a cheap crappy PSU.

Any idea on how to fix this? I'd rather not buy a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning all the psu connectors and their relative "ports" on all your piece of hardware, I had an issue with my GPU (it continue rebooting randomly, I thought at a psu problem) and cleaning the connectors completely solved the problem. Excuse me for my bad English, I hope I've wrote something understandable

Comment: How will cleaning psu connectors help with a buzzing sound (which presumably relates to varying current draw ?)

Comment: Also my issue was related to varying current consumption, the vga crashed only on high state, and cleaning the connectors seems to have solved the problem. However the best thing to do is to try whit a different Ethernet board with similar consumption to see if the issue is the board or the psu